# Click links to load the relevant image into a container

Tags: jquery, image, click, fadein

I have some links that when you click on them, i need them to load an image into a container, and when you click the close link, it hides it again.

I have an example of it here but unsure how to apply the images into the div with the link if this makes sense:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/1/

I assume i need something along the lines of this....

```
<a class="click" href= "#" src="image/location">Click here to fadeIn the image in a container</a>
```

I am going to have many links with the images and the container will stay the same.

What is the best and efficient way to start this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("a.click").click(function (event) {
        //hide panel in case it's already visible because of a previously loaded image
        $("#hiddenPanel").fadeOut(0);
        //disable default link click event so page does not change if link has a href
        event.preventDefault();
        //set links src to the src of image in the hidden panel 
        $("#hiddenPanel img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $("#hiddenPanel").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $("#closeButton").click(function () {
        $("#hiddenPanel").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/22/)

You may want to fade out image slowly instead of fadeOut(0) if it's visible, and load the new one after fade out is complete.

Comment: Thanks! I assime tht the event.preventDefault(); is to stop the page from refreshing, hide the hidden container and then when the link with the class a is clicked, the image with the src attribute thats been clicked fades in.

Comment: Building this properly tomorrow- will let you know how i get on!

Comment: Yes if you do not prevent default click event, it will try to load the link and if the link has an actual href it will navigate to that page.

Answer (score 0):

html right here

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="image.png">click me to show</a>

 <div style="display: none;">
  <img src="noimg.png" />
  <a href="#"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

and jquery here

```
$('.wrapper > a').click(function(event) {
 var thisSrc = $(this).attr('href');
 var thisImg = $(this).next().children('img');

 thisImg.attr('src', thisSrc);
 $(this).next().show();
 event.preventDefault();
});

$('.wrapper > div > a').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

I think it is simple way to do this... also you can type functions to do this and than run this functions on click event...

and you can style markup wothout element style :))